# Best way to implement background image on HTML or body

Tags: html, css

I have an image which i need to stretch whole body so i don't know what is best way to do this

```
html{
  /*background image properties*/
}
```

or

```
body{
  /*background image properties*/
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```css
body{
    background-image:url('../images/background.jpg');
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This would be the best way, you could apply it to the HTML, it really depends on what you prefer...

```css
background-image:url('../images/background.jpg');
```

Assuming your css file is in a different map, you do ../ to go to the map in which your css folder is placed, then you go into the images file and select the image.

```css
background-attachment:fixed;
```

When setting a background-image I personally like to use this, it makes it so that when a user scrolls, the background-image maintains it's current position.

```css
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

When using this setting, it makes it so that the image won't repeat, in case it is too small or just won't cover the whole background.

```css
background-size: cover;
```

When you apply this you will set the background-size to cover, combined with `no-repeat` and `attachment: fixed` it makes for a good way to style your background image

Comment: Hi Gerwin, I am using your css style. But image is getting distorted on a desktop. The image size is 9MB and 3250*2164 in dimension. I want this image to fit perfectly in a background of screen without any distortion. what are the additional attributes I need ?

Comment: @Lokesh Hey man, what is the resolution of the image? It could be that the image gets warped / distorted because either: 1. The image can't scale to the device resolution or the other way around, 2. The image is corrupt / damaged by someone editting it or 3. the image itself is warped / distorted, good luck!

Comment: Hi Gerwin the image is 3250 pixels in width and 2164 pixels in height. The image is able to scale to the device resolution. I tested it in toggle device toolbar.

Comment: @Lokesh how big is the screen?

Comment: the screen is 1366x768

Comment: @LokeshIt's the screen, it's a low-cost LED display, it's a issue the your image or code, try putting a image on the screen with 1366 x 768 as a resolution

Answer (score 3):

As per the CSS 2.1 Specs here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background

> For HTML documents, however, we recommend that authors specify the
>   background for the BODY element rather than the HTML element. For
>   documents whose root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an XHTML
>   "html" element that has computed values of 'transparent' for
>   'background-color' and 'none' for 'background-image', user agents must
>   instead use the computed value of the background properties from that
>   element's first HTML "BODY" element or XHTML "body" element child when
>   painting backgrounds for the canvas, and must not paint a background
>   for that child element....

Hence, it is ***recommended*** to use a `background` on `body` (rather than on `html`).

If you want a `background-image` to stretch the whole container (i.e. `body`), then you could use the style:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

If you want to preserve the aspect ratio, then you could use `cover` to make it cover the full container, or use `contain` to keep it within the container boundary. When you use `contain`, then depending on the aspect ratio of the background image, you could end up with white-space below or after the image ends (letterbox).

```
background-image: url('...');
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
...
```

.

Comment: Hi Abhitalks, I am using your css style. But image is getting distorted on a desktop. The image size is 9MB and 3250*2164 in dimension. I want this image to fit perfectly in a background of screen without any distortion. what are the additional attributes I need ?

Answer (score 1):

```
body{
  /*background image properties*/
}
```

this would be the best way, since body is the immediate parent of all elements which are visible on the webpage.

http://jsfiddle.net/hxyz2evq/

You can use `background-size:contain;` to cover all the area with background image

```
body{
width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background:url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Bachalpseeflowers.jpg);
    background-cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

**Note**: Also there is a case I think of:

```
<html>
    <head>
        some free data
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

here the `some free data` will get displayed inside the webpage, i.e inside `body`, so we wouldnt care about giving the background property to `html tag`,

just using `body{//background properties }` is fine

```
Edit:
```

Though this is not the question for what property should be used here. There can be various things like:

```
background-size:cover;
OR
background-contain;
OR
background-100% 100%;
```

The best property which suits your question would be `background-100% 100%;`

Comment: It should be `background-size:cover`, shouldn't it?

Comment: If you are using `background-100% 100%;` that would stretch the background image

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{
    background-image:url('../images/background.jpg');
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, I would use in body.

```
body{
  background-image: url(path.jpg);/*wearing a cloth in body instead of heart*/
}
```

Seems to be applied in whole body semantically.

Answer (score 0):

You should target the `body` tag and apply the `background-size` property to it.

Like so

```
body{
background-size: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use**

```
body{
background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Bachalpseeflowers.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Background to fit screen</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Imagetoolbar" content="no">

<style type="text/css">
/* pushes the page to the full capacity of the viewing area */
html {height:100%;}
body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
/* prepares the background image to full capacity of the viewing area */
#bg {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
/* places the content ontop of the background image */
#content {position:relative; z-index:1;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="bg"><img src="yourimage.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt=""></div>
<div id="content"><p>Enter a ton of text or whatever here.</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Example : [Check this](http://www.htmlite.com/faqEX004b.html)

Answer (score 0):

The CSS3 background-size:cover property handles full screen background images, including responsivity, quite well. The below works well for me on all desktop and mobile devices I've tested.

```
body { 
    background-image: url(/assets/img/yourimage.jpg); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;       
    webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height:100%;
    width:100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background:no-repeat url(' ') #154454 bottom center ;
background-size:contain;


body {
    background-image: url(/_assets/img/zoom-17536689-3.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: While what you have written may answer the question, however it does seem a little lacking in [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) and may illicit confusion to other users. Can you please expand upon your answer so that it is clearer and more accessible? This will make for better answers and help future users understand how the problem was solved.

Comment: I'm using an English translation and this may mislead you. I can only make corrections to the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bk
{
  background: url('../assets/imgs/img.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

put it between the body tags, sample code below
Set two background images for the  element:

```
body {
  background-image: url("img_tree.gif"), url("paper.gif");
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

The full manual can be read here [CSS background-image Property](https://sourcecode.nusapos.com/css/np-9759/css-background-image-property)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you affiliated with, or the author of the linked article? If so, please note that when linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33022489)