# Why did a full background image work for body but not html in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I did the following in CSS and it didn't change the webpage:

```
html {

                background:url("image.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover;
            }
```

But then I did the following code and the background changed how I wanted it to:

```
body {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                background:url("image.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover;
            }
```

It doesn't make sense why the html call would not update it but the body would.

The rest of the code is blank except for the Bootstrap framework I'm using.

Comment: Seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939027/best-way-to-implement-background-image-on-html-or-body

Comment: So if you removed the head then?

Comment: @ArnaudRochez — What do you mean "you cannot style the head"? http://jsbin.com/dujizecuto/1/edit?html,output

Comment: @Quentin You're right apparently, removing my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The rest of the code is blank except for the Bootstrap framework I'm using

… and that is your problem.

The Bootstrap CSS sets a background colour on the body element.

> ```
> body{font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:1.42857143;color:#333;background-color:#fff}
> ```

— [source](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css)

This covers up any background you apply to the HTML element.

Setting `body { background: transparent }` would override that.