# does not display the background-image

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following problem. I can't display the image in the blade template. I use bootstrap and laravel 5.8. I've tried different options (without asset, with / ahead). Folder img in public.

Code blade and html from browser below.

blade

```html
<div class="carousel-item-a intro-item bg-image"
     style="background-image: url({{asset('img/slide-1.jpg')}})">
```

chrome

```html
<div class="carousel-item-a intro-item bg-image"
     style="background-image: url(http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/slide-1.jpg)">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [best way to implement background image on HTML or body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939027/best-way-to-implement-background-image-on-html-or-body)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Looks like you should concatenate string with php code.

```
<div class="carousel-item-a intro-item bg-image"
     style="background-image:url('". {{asset('img/slide-1.jpg')}}."')">
```

Comment: Not working <div class="carousel-item-a intro-item bg-image"
             style="background-image:".url(http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/slide-1.jpg)>

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I've just edit the answer, please check it again.

Comment: Not working. Wrong path  <div class="carousel-item-a intro-item bg-image"
             style="background-image:url(". http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/slide-1.jpg.")")>

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Please check correct syntax