# how to position image at background of text in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on viewport elements in CSS and want background to be an image from unsplash.com website

I tried images from online website which doesn't work for background image but local computer works well

```css
header {
  background: #333 ('https://unsplash.com/photos/0J3_p-xc9s8');
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Welcome to my Website</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime officiis eveniet possimus saepe, deleniti neque?</p>
  <a href="#" class="btn">see more</a>
</header>
```

I expect to come a background image but nothing occurs.

Comment: the url `https://unsplash.com/photos/0J3_p-xc9s8` is not an image, by accessing it via browser it goes to a site with an image inside, but it is not the URL directly to the image. The correct would be: `https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569255726521-d2e663a80283?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80`

Answer (score 2):

`url` is missing!
Also, you have to use the image url. Not the unslplash's one...

Use this instead:

`background: #333 url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569255726521-d2e663a80283?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1051&q=80');`

Answer (score 0):

Give proper `url` and `background-size: cover;`

```css
header{
      color: white;
      line-height: 1.7em;
      height: 100vh;
      padding: 2rem;
      background: #333 url(http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png);
      background-size: cover;
 }
```

```html
 <header>
        <h1>Welcome to my Website</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
        Maxime officiis eveniet possimus saepe, deleniti neque?</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">see more</a>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Duplicate [best way to implement background image on HTML or body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939027/best-way-to-implement-background-image-on-html-or-body)
2. URL is missing.
3. You are not giving an image link, but a webpage link.

Comment: If it's a duplicate then you should vote to close as a duplicate and not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

you must open open image in new tab to select the real image link path
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569255726521-d2e663a80283?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80

and try to add the url(img_url) value.
Try to use style:

```
header {
  color: #fff;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569255726521-d2e663a80283?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80);

  line-height: 1.7em;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```