# Background image gets cut out, or a scroll bar gets added

Tags: html, css, image, background, background-image

I am using the following code to set a background image to my HTML:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: url('images/lightning.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;  
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

But the image did not show up entirely on the screen so I tried the following solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/507w9yoa/ which doesn't work as well.

Could someone please help me set the background image without adding the scroll bar or cutting off the images? I have tried all solutions available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939027/best-way-to-implement-background-image-on-html-or-body/27939180) and other site but nothing seems to work.

Comment: first, `background-size` property is supported by every browser (even IE). It does not need any prefix cinse about 8 years. Instead of `cover` us `contain`. `background-size: contain;` will make the image maintain its aspect ratio but not crop.

Comment: background-size: contain may be what you want, but for a background image it can look odd (if e.g. it's to be a background for the whole page) on different viewports with very different aspect ratios. Is it what you want?

Comment: @tacoshy and @A Haworth, I want my image to fill the screen as well.

Comment: if you want the image to fill the screen and not to be cut, it will be streched. As such it will not be able to maintain its aspect ratio and might look very odd. Logically you cant achieve a full cover without deforming the image if the viewport and the image do not have the evry same aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

**contain**

`contain` will maintain the aspect ratio and fit the screen either vertically or horizontally. It will not crop the image but therefor not fill the entire background unless the aspect ratio is the exact same.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: url('https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't fill the screen

Answer (score 0):

Try this out: I just used 2 different units in background-size and now image works as for the screen size, image doesn't gets cropped and fills screen.  I tried different screen and it worked fine for me.

```css
body {
  background: url('https://i.postimg.cc/1tcWpbZY/pexels-plato-terentev-5822191.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```css
body {
    background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Standard_time_zones_of_the_world_%282012%29_-_Pacific_Centered.svg") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}
```

This might stretch weird but won't add any scroll bar and won't cut your image.