# How do I add a background image in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have been trying to add my background image in CSS but nothing is working for me. I tried a few YouTube videos but nothing. Can anyone help me please? I have a folder called "Image" inside of my main folder called "CSS_animation" just for context.

HTML

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <title>CSS Animation</title>
  </head>

  <body>
  <main>

  <nav>
  <ul>
  <li class="one"><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li class="two"><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li class="three"><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  </main>
  </body>
  </html>
```

CSS

```
  body
  {
  background-image: url("Image/FreshFarmsBG.jpg");

  }
```

Comment: Have you checked your dev tools for errors?

Comment: I'm using codepen.io and I checked my console and nothing is wrong but then when I go on dreamweaver and try to view it in google chrome the page will not up load. It shows up with an error saying " Save all the files (including related files) to preview." but I have everything saved? I'm lost.

Comment: Can you please share your complete file tree structure ?

Comment: I just checked and now the image is up. It works through style in html. So then I guess my css isn't connected to my html?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [best way to implement background image on HTML or body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939027/best-way-to-implement-background-image-on-html-or-body)

Comment: Thank you but it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but check url maybe it is "./image/FreshFarmsBG.jpg" (with small i) or maybe just try to add this in css

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly test it within the HTML file with a `<style>` tag within the `<head>` tag and insert your CSS inside the style tag...

```
<head>
      <style>
        body {
             background-image: url("desiredPathHere");
        }
      </style>
</head>
```

If this works then the link you have created to your stylesheet is probably incorrect...

Comment: Have you ensured your file path is correct?

Comment: Yes I have. It's fixed now, thanks!